# Remove dot and keep leading zero in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a column in Excel with values that looks like this:

```
01.01
01.02
01.03
01.04
01.05
01.06
0101.2
0101.21.00
0101.21.00.00
0101.29.00
0101.29.00.10
```

I am trying to remove the "." in the 4 digit cells i.e. 01.01 01.02 etc. so that they will show 0101, 0102 instead.  The current cells indicated "General" format.  I changed it to "text".  Then tried to do a replace "." to blank.  However, it will change from 01.01 to 101.  I have tried several methods including "custom" format to no avail.

I filtered the column so only those cells with length=5 show up.  I then applied a "custom" format 0000 to the cells.  It changed.  However, I then tried to sort the column, it will not sort properly.  The custom formatted 4-digit cells are conflicting with other cells.

I only need to remove the "." for those 4-digit cells and keeping the leading zero.  Seems like an easy task but I am pulling my hair. Any advise is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different interpretation:

```
=IF(MID(A1,3,1)=".",REPLACE(A1,3,1,),A1)
```

May sort as you require.

Change `,`s for `;`s if necessary for your configuration.

Comment: Works great.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When `A1` is your target cell,

```
B1=SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")
```

---

In my photo Column A is formatted as `Text` and Column B is good ol' fashion `General`

[image]

Comment: it says "The formula you typed contains an error".  I only need to convert the one with 4-digits thou.